# Can't get my SQL query to work with php

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I am using a query to get data organized and it works well with ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER, though when I am trying to get it in my PHP script, it returns an error.

---

My php file:

```
<?php
    include 'connexion.php';
    //


    $sql  = oci_parse($conn, 'select c.* from ( 
    select 
    b.EB_DOMAINE_NOM,b.EB_INDICATEUR_LIBELLE,b.EB_RESULTAT_VALEUR as EB_RESULTAT_VALEUR_m,
    b.EB_RESULTAT_INSERT_DATE as EB_RESULTAT_INSERT_DATE_m,
    b.EB_INDICATEUR_NUM, 
    EB_RESULTAT_DTM.VALEUR as valeur_m1,(EB_RESULTAT_DTM.VALEUR-b.EB_RESULTAT_VALEUR) as diff_m1_m,
    rank() over (partition by EB_RESULTAT_DTM.X_EB_INDICATEUR_DTM_NUM, to_char(EB_RESULTAT_DTM.INSERT_DATE,'yyyymm') 
    order by to_char(EB_RESULTAT_DTM.INSERT_DATE,'yyyymmdd') asc) as rang
    from (
    select A.*  
    from (
    SELECT EB_DOMAINE_DTM."NOM" AS EB_DOMAINE_NOM,
             EB_INDICATEUR_DTM."LIBELLE" AS EB_INDICATEUR_LIBELLE,
             EB_RESULTAT_DTM."VALEUR" AS EB_RESULTAT_VALEUR, 
             EB_RESULTAT_DTM."INSERT_DATE" AS EB_RESULTAT_INSERT_DATE,
             EB_INDICATEUR_DTM."INDICATEUR_NUM" AS EB_INDICATEUR_NUM,
             rank() over (partition by EB_INDICATEUR_DTM.INDICATEUR_NUM,to_char(EB_RESULTAT_DTM.INSERT_DATE,'yyyymm') order by to_char(EB_RESULTAT_DTM.INSERT_DATE,'yyyymmdd') asc) as rang,
             to_char(EB_RESULTAT_DTM.INSERT_DATE,'yyyymm') as MOIS_M
        FROM "COMPTEUR_OWNER"."EB_DOMAINE_DTM" EB_DOMAINE_DTM
             INNER JOIN
             "COMPTEUR_OWNER"."EB_INDICATEUR_DTM" EB_INDICATEUR_DTM
                ON EB_DOMAINE_DTM."EB_DOMAINE_DTM_NUM" =
                      EB_INDICATEUR_DTM."X_EB_DOMAINE_DTM_NUM"
             INNER JOIN
             "COMPTEUR_OWNER"."EB_RESULTAT_DTM" EB_RESULTAT_DTM
                ON EB_INDICATEUR_DTM."INDICATEUR_NUM" =
                      EB_RESULTAT_DTM."X_EB_INDICATEUR_DTM_NUM"
       WHERE     EB_INDICATEUR_DTM."INDICATEUR_NUM" = 106
             AND EB_RESULTAT_DTM."INSERT_DATE" BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -9) 
                                                   AND SYSDATE
    ) a where a.rang=1
    ) b left outer join COMPTEUR_OWNER.EB_RESULTAT_DTM EB_RESULTAT_DTM 
    on EB_RESULTAT_DTM.X_EB_INDICATEUR_DTM_NUM =b.EB_INDICATEUR_NUM 
    AND TO_CHAR(EB_RESULTAT_DTM.INSERT_DATE,'YYYYMM')=TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(b.MOIS_M,'YYYYMM'),1),'YYYYMM') 
    ) c where c.rang=1
    order by TO_CHAR(c.EB_RESULTAT_INSERT_DATE_m,'YYYYMM') asc

    ');

    oci_execute($sql);
```

### ?>

I get an error because of the `'YYYYMM'`. Or if I fix it I get an error with `A.RANG` etc..

---

While in Oracle I get what I want:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/2snvnWu.png]

---

Is there a way to get the same result as in Oracle?

Comment: escape the `'` inside your string with `\'`.... then start reading the PHP manual page about [strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using single quotes in your query. the single quotes is what is breaking php. n00b mistake. All you have to do is wrap your sql statement in double quotes, not single quotes. Or alternatively escape the single quote with a \

Comment: Note that there's also double quotes in this SQL statement, so they would need escaping if the whole string was wrapped in double quotes rather than in single quotes... heredoc would probably be better

Comment: Yep, noticed and amended my answer to include escaping with a \ :)

Comment: Thank you. I just put the SQL statement into double quotes and leave the 'YYYYMM'. I had the problem with 

`SELECT EB_DOMAINE_DTM."NOM" AS EB_DOMAINE_NOM,
             EB_INDICATEUR_DTM."LIBELLE" AS EB_INDICATEUR_LIBELLE,
             EB_RESULTAT_DTM."VALEUR" AS EB_RESULTAT_VALEUR, 
             EB_RESULTAT_DTM."INSERT_DATE" AS EB_RESULTAT_INSERT_DATE,
             EB_INDICATEUR_DTM."INDICATEUR_NUM" AS EB_INDICATEUR_NUM,`

due to the doubles quotes... 

I just deleted them at this point and it worked. Thanks